# Tab and line separation in python pandas

Tags: python

I have the attached file which I need to upload in python. I need to ignore `NETSIM` and `10` value on top and read the remaining. I used the following code to read the file in python:

```
import pandas as pd
x=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/oq/Desktop/FAST/Algorithms/project/benchmark/input10.txt',sep=r'\\\t',engine='python',skiprows=(0,1,2), header=None)
```

I used the tab separator in my code but the output is still show me as follows:

```
0                               0\t0.362291\t0.441396
1                               1\t0.156279\t0.341383
2                               2\t0.699696\t0.045577
3                               3\t0.714313\t0.171668
4                               4\t0.378966\t0.495494
5                               5\t0.961942\t0.444337
6                               6\t0.726886\t0.575888
7                               7\t0.168639\t0.406223
8                               8\t0.875627\t0.061439
9                               9\t0.540054\t0.317061
10  5\t7\t155200000.000000\t54000000.000000\t37997...
11  3\t4\t155200000.000000\t40500000.000000\t24507...
12  4\t6\t155200000.000000\t33000000.000000\t18606...
13  5\t6\t155200000.000000\t72000000.000000\t39198...
14  4\t1\t155200000.000000\t40500000.000000\t24507...
15  3\t9\t155200000.000000\t39000000.000000\t22698...
```

Can someone please guide me as to what's wrong?

[The attached file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeHzU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to split on a literal tab character, not the string `\\t`, so you shouldn't be using a raw string literal here.  Change `sep` to just `'\t'`.

```
x=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/oq/Desktop/FAST/Algorithms/project/benchmark/input10.txt',sep='\t',engine='python',skiprows=(0,1,2), header=None)
```

Comment: I tried a single \t as well. Python gives me the following error when I use it:

Comment: ParserError: Expected 3 fields in line 17, saw 21. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Comment: @OmerQureshi Try removing the `r` from the front of `sep`, e.g. `sep='\t'`.